# UI Automater viwer is not opening

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

When I'm double clicking on the uiautomatorviewer.bat file the command prompt opening and immediately closing itself.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Right-click on the shortcut, select "edit"  Copy the command line into memory (ctrl-C)  Open a command prompt and paste the command into the command prompt and press Enter.  There should be your reason - probably cannot locate the program, but whatever the error message, you should be able to see it.

Answer (score 2):

You might have not set path variable or have multiple uiautomator.bat files like at two different instances.

Or can try to open from command line by navigating to drive path where bat file located and enter "uiautomatorviewer" Screenshot attached[https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh1mU.png]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are not set the environment variable path, Please check if it is not please follow the instruction: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/setup-android-environment-variables/